# FasttextR encoding

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, fasttext

FasttextR is reading some Spanish words wrong in R (e.g.,  "participaciÃ³n". for "participación")from the pre-trained model "cc.es.300.bin" that I download from their website (https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/crawl-vectors.html).

I think the issue is that when I upload the model I have no way to tell R that the encoding should be "UTF-8", and not "Latin1" or others. That is, I can load the Spanish model and get the words wrong, like this:

```
model <- ft_load("cc.es.300.bin")
```

but I cannot do this:

```
model <- ft_load("cc.es.300.bin", encoding="UTF-8")
```

as it is possible to do with xlsx files, for example:

```
model <- xlsx::read.xlsx("file.xlsx", sheetIndex = 1, encoding="UTF-8")
```

I have tried: changing the language and encoding in Windows; reopening and saving the .R file with UTF-8 encoding; changing the locale to Spanish by `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "Spanish")`. Nothing worked.

Any help will be much appreciated.
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The library "readr" helped me

```
install.packages("read")
library(readr)
```

```
guess_encoding(ft_words(model))

|                                                                                        |   0%
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  encoding  confidence
  <chr>          <dbl>
1 UTF-8           1   
2 Shift_JIS       0.31
```

```
parse_character(ft_words(model), locale=locale(encoding="UTF-8"))
   [1] "de"              ","               "."               "la"              "y"              
   [6] "en"              "que"             "el"              "</s>"            "a"              
  [11] "los"             ":"               "\""              "del"             "un"             
  [16] ")"               "se"              "con"             "por"             "las"            
  [21] "("               "para"            "una"             "es"              "no"             
  [26] "su"              "al"              "como"            "lo"              "/"              
  [31] "más"             "El"              "o"               "'"               "La"             
  [36] "!"               "|"               "?"               "me"              "En"             
  [41] "..."             "-"               "sus"             "este"            "pero"           
  [46] "ha"              "esta"            ";"               "“"               "_"              
  [51] "”"               "si"              "sobre"           "¿"               "fue"            
  [56] "son"             "le"              "muy"             "ser"             "ya"             
  [61] "tu"              "todo"            "1"               "entre"           "te"             
  [66] "mi"              "Los"             "%"               "sin"             "también"
...
```

instead of

```
 [1] "de"               ","                "."                "la"              
   [5] "y"                "en"               "que"              "el"              
   [9] "</s>"             "a"                "los"              ":"               
  [13] "\""               "del"              "un"               ")"               
  [17] "se"               "con"              "por"              "las"             
  [21] "("                "para"             "una"              "es"              
  [25] "no"               "su"               "al"               "como"            
  [29] "lo"               "/"                "mÃ¡s"             "El"              
  [33] "o"                "'"                "La"               "!"               
  [37] "|"                "?"                "me"               "En"              
  [41] "..."              "-"                "sus"              "este"            
  [45] "pero"             "ha"               "esta"             ";"               
  [49] "â€œ"              "_"                "â€\u009d"         "si"              
  [53] "sobre"            "Â¿"               "fue"              "son"             
  [57] "le"               "muy"              "ser"              "ya"
```

However, it does not seem to help when I use functions to get nearest neighbors

```
parse_character(ft_nearest_neighbors(model, "pera", k = 10L), locale=locale(encoding="UTF-8"))
Error in parse_vector(x, col_character(), na = na, locale = locale, trim_ws = trim_ws) : 
  is.character(x) is not TRUE
```

but (notice piÃ±a instead of piña)

```
ft_nearest_neighbors(model, "pera", k = 10L)
 limonera   ciruela   manzana mandarina     piÃ±a     fruta   sandÃ­a   compota    sandia     fresa 
0.6326169 0.6112964 0.6079050 0.5713655 0.5707002 0.5576053 0.5557024 0.5526152 0.5485740 0.5437940
```

Now, what helps is enc2utf8 (still, the characters in the output look funny)

```
ft_nearest_neighbors(model,enc2utf8("piña"), k = 10L)
  sandÃ­a    papaya    sandia    ananÃ¡  plÃ¡tano   ananÃ¡s     fruta    limÃ³n mandarina maracuyÃ¡ 
0.6763531 0.6571828 0.6365163 0.6341625 0.6205474 0.6205293 0.6137358 0.6037553 0.6032383 0.5941805
```

enc2utf8 also helps if you want to obtain individual word vectors

```
piña <- as.vector(ft_word_vectors(model, enc2utf8("piña")))
```